# Set YouTube video title when uploading with Node.js (googleapi module v1.0)

Tags: node.js, upload, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to upload video to my YouTube channel using the `googleapi` module in Node.js (YouTube API V3)

The video is uploaded fine - I just can't find how to pass title and description to the upload command.

This is my code:

```
//Authorization stuff above

fs.readFile('./youtube_videos/in.avi', function(err, content){
    if(err){
        console.log('read file error: '+err);
    } else {
        yt.videos.insert({
            part: 'status,snippet',
            autoLevels: true,
            media: {
                body: content
            }
        }, function(error, data){
            if(error){
                console.log('error: '+error);
            } else {
                console.log('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+data.id+"\r\n\r\n");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

I know how should pass some `snippet` object like

```
snippet: {
    title: 'test upload2',
    description: 'My description2',
}
```

but I can't find where should it be - I tried every (almost) combination possible

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer
In case someone is looking for it - 
The snippet should be part of a `resource` object in the options of the request

(I also converted the `fs.readFile` to `fs.createReadStream`)

```
function uploadToYoutube(video_file, title, description,tokens, callback){
    var google = require("googleapis"),
        yt = google.youtube('v3');

    var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, appSecret, redirectUrl);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    google.options({auth: oauth2Client});

    return yt.videos.insert({
        part: 'status,snippet',
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                title: title,
                description: description
            },
            status: { 
                privacyStatus: 'private' //if you want the video to be private
            }
        },
        media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream(video_file)
        }
    }, function(error, data){
        if(error){
            callback(error, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data.id);
        }
    });
};
```